# FeedComment insertion does not generate Chatter email

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter, feeditem, feedcomment

I was able to create an automated FeedItem trigger that fires and automatically replies (from a dummy user) to a user when he/she makes posting.

I did not get the typical "commented on your post" emails from Chatter. Is there a way to enable this in my code?

Best,
Eric

Comment: Did you look in the Connect API?

Comment: Can you post your trigger code? The Connect API won't work because it only supports posting as the current user.

Comment: You could also try using a @future method to call the commenting code asynchronously. It may be the case that the comment needs to happen in a separate transaction in order to generate the email notification (just a guess).

Comment: @alouie it is an After Insert Trigger

Comment: What technique are you using to run this as a different user? A typical after trigger that inserts a FeedComment would run as the current user and would therefore not notify the user because it is a comment on their own post.

Comment: It is running as the user that is being @ mentioned. For example, you (Rick) is OOO. You set your OOO chatter in SFDC. I @mention you. I receive an immediate response from you notifying me that you are away.